# How can I calculate or memorize the profit and loss status of the last transaction in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

How can I calculate or memorize the profit and loss status of the last transaction in Pine Script?
For example,
If my last trade lost 10%, I want to use a different condition in the next trade. So I need to be able to calculate or memorize the last transaction.
Thank you for helpings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need one built-in function and one built-in variable for that.

> ***strategy.closedtrades.profit()***: Returns the profit/loss of the closed
> trade. Losses are expressed as negative values.
>
> ***strategy.closedtrades***: Number of trades, which were closed for the
> whole trading interval.

So, what you want to do is feed number of trades into `strategy.closedtrades.profit()` function.

Here is an example:

```
//@version=5
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, pyramiding=1)

pl = strategy.closedtrades.profit(strategy.closedtrades - 1) + strategy.closedtrades.commission(strategy.closedtrades - 1)
strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, when = open[1] > close[1])
strategy.entry("sell", strategy.short, when = open[1] < close[1])

plot(pl, color=color.orange)
plot(strategy.closedtrades, color=color.red)
```

[image]

Comment: Anything similar for v4?

Comment: @dorien, you need to come up with your own solution. But why not use v5? It has these and much more useful features.

Comment: Agreed, but it would mean changing a huge script that is currently in production, and I’d need some dedicated time to do that properly.

Comment: You can use the converter tool. From v4 to v5, it should convert without any issues.

Comment: There is a converter! Ok did that... did all ok except one thing, but that is a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73982008/check-for-strategy-long-just-opened-in-pine-script-v5