# Check for strategy.long just opened in pine script v5

Tags: pine-script

In my v4 script, I use the below to mark on a graph if a buy signal was received:

```
if strategy.long 
        stratstring := 'Buy'
```

In v5 strategy.long is no longer a bool, but a strategy_direction. How do I change the if statement. I imagine something like

```
if strategy.long == strategy_direction.long
```

but that does not exist...

Basically, I want to detect if a long signal was given in the current bar.

Comment: `strategy.position_size  >0 ` will return `true` if in long position. Will this work? Or you’re looking for something else?

Comment: I'm looking for something that flags true only if a buy was issued at the current bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you are not already in a long trade and if your long condition is true as below:

```
buy_now = (strategy.position_size <= 0) and your_long_condition
```

Comment: Yeah I could, but the script is quite complex, with many different long conditions spread throughout, so was just wondering if there was an easy way to find a way to print custom buy labels on the graph (hence the if condition).

Comment: But it should only be true if the buy signal was given in the current bar, not in a previous bar (and still open).